# Can't echo JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I can't access my json and would like to know where the error is.

```
$json = json_encode($data);
// string(1065) "[{"id":"test123","key":["one",...
```

Then I decode it to make it accessable via this command:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);

// Output:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(14) "test123"
```

When I want to echo it, it gives me:

```
echo $json[0];
```

> Array to string conversion in

Comment: print_r($json[0]);

Comment: `$json[0]` is an array. You cannot `echo` an array.

Comment: `echo $json[0]['id'];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `print_r` for array, `echo` is used to display a `string` that's why it's giving error.

```
print_r($json);
```